# Reading value from Spring Property file

Tags: java, spring, properties

Here is my code I'm trying to read " TestMe variable from My.properties file.

```
public class TestToCheckProperties {

    private int testMe;

      public void setTestMe(int testMe) {
    this.testMe = testMe;
        }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/META-INF/spring/bean/dfp-web-beans.xml");
        TestToCheckProperties testToCheckProperties=context.getBean(TestToCheckProperties);
        System.out.println("testMe: "+testToCheckProperties.testMe);
}
```

This is in my Spring.XML 
I've created a bean for class TestToCheckProperties:

```
<bean id='TestToCheckProperties' class="com.My.Code.TestToCheckProperties"  >
        <property name="testMe" value="${My.code.TestToCheckProperties}" />
    </bean>
```

This is in my My.Property file and I'm trying to read this value in my class:

```
#TestToCheckProperties
My.code.TestToCheckProperties=10
```

Here is the error I'm getting

Comment: Did you post before your were finished writing your question? Where is your error? Post the rest of your context configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement:

```
TestToCheckProperties testToCheckProperties = 
    context.getBean(TestToCheckProperties);
```

is invalid. It should rather be:

```
TestToCheckProperties testToCheckProperties = 
    (TestToCheckProperties) context.getBean("TestToCheckProperties");
```